# How can I create and use a variable inside docker?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to get the version from a pom file so that I can use it later in another command. So inside the docker file I have,

```
RUN VERSION="$(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version|grep -Ev '(^\[|Download\w+:)')" 
RUN echo $VERSION
```

But the echo prints nothing. What I actually want to run is,

```
RUN mv /abc/abc-${VERSION}.jar /abc/abc.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you group your 2 lines in one, it will work

`RUN VERSION="$(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version|grep -Ev '(^\[|Download\w+:)')"  ; echo $VERSION`

the recommended way is of course the solution proposed by Ilya Peterov, I suspect you want to use it later in your Dockerfile

I will take another example, if you have a script in abc/myscript.sh

`RUN cd abc ; ./myscript`

will work, while

`RUN cd abc
RUN ./myscript`

will fail as it will not be in the abc directory

Answer (score 2):

Use `ENV` like that, it's the way Docker devs want you to do it:

```
ENV VERSION "$(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version|grep -Ev '(^\[|Download\w+:)')" 
RUN echo $VERSION
```

There is an example is the docs that's very similar to your case: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement